# How to GRANT in mysql after REVOKE

Tags: mysql

In mysql i executed following command 
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES
after that i try to give GRANT then it shows Access denied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it would seem that you revoked the `GRANT` privileges of your own user, you should use the root user to grant those privileges back.

for a review of your status regarding the privileges run from root user:

```
SHOW GRANTS;
```